# How to override a Play 2.0 dependency at runtime?

Tags: sbt, playframework-2.0

I need to override a runtime dependency of play2.0 in my project.
Running `play dependencies` on a play 2.0 project I can see

> com.google.guava:guava:10.0.1 | org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-api:2.16.1,  play:play_2.9.1:2.0  |As guava.jar

but my application has a dependency towards guava:12.0-rc2.

How can I override this dependency using sbt or else?

Answer (score 3):

Just add the following dependency in your build.scala:

> "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "12.0-rc2"

or from the sbt command line (in your project directory):

> set seq(Seq(libraryDependencies += "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "12.0-rc2"): _*)
>
> show dependency-classpath

**show dependency-classpath** will display if the download was successful.